# Querying Active Directory using C# for user email by employee ID

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Is it possible to get a user's email from Active Directory using employeenumber as the query term?

I am using C#'s `System.DirectoryServices` and am a little bit lost. The previous developer at my company was using this process, but he had an email and was querying for the employee number. I have changed it to what I believe it should be, but to be honest, I don't understand the code that well.

Is there something wrong with my code? every time i run it, I get a Null Reference error on the `DirectoryEntry up_user =` line. I assume it is because the previous line is not getting any entities.

Also, is there any good documentation on this topic? Everywhere I look, the posts are from 2011 or 2013.

I have the following:

```
try
{
    string email = string.Empty;
    ContextType authenticationType = ContextType.Domain;
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType, "MATRIC");
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;

    userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, empnum);

    DirectoryEntry up_User = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
    DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(up_User);
    SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
    if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
    {
        ResultPropertyCollection rpc = results[0].Properties;
        foreach (string rp in rpc.PropertyNames)
        {
            if (rp == "mail") 
            {
                email = rpc["mail"][0].ToString();
            }
        }

        if (email != string.Empty)
        {
            return email;
        }

        return null;
    }
            return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your issue is that your object keeps returning null. Have you checked out this link and explored those options -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050930/userprincipal-findbyidentity-always-returns-null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` only works for finding a user by what AD considers an identifying attribute. These are listed in the [`IdentityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype) enumeration. The employee number isn't one of those.

Are you using `employeeId` or `employeeNumber` in AD? They are different attributes, although both are just strings with no special meaning or restrictions in AD.

The `employeeId` attribute is exposed in the `UserPrincipal` class, so you can search by it with `UserPrincipal` as described in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346785/1202807):

```
UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
searchTemplate.EmployeeID = employeeId;
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);

UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
```

Then you can use the `EmailAddress` property of the account you find (you don't need to do what you're doing with the `DirectorySearcher`).

```
var emailAddress user?.EmailAddress;
```

If you're using `employeeNumber`, then you will need to use `DirectorySearcher` to find it. Something like this:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://yourdomain.com"));
search.Filter = $"(&(ObjectClass=user)(employeeNumber={employeeNumber}))"; 
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

var result = search.FindOne();
string emailAddress = null;
if (result.Properties.Contains("mail")) {
    emailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].Value as string;
}
```

Comment: I am using employeeNumber. So in the last block of code, the Filter says get users where employeeNumber = the EmployeeNumber I provide? Then it only loads `mail`. In the result it finds the first match of the employeeNumber and sets emailAddress to the search result?  Sorry i just want to understand it

Comment: Right. So that code assumes you have a variable called `employeeNumber` already. Then it sets `emailAddress` to the `mail` attribute of the user it found.